# Loading all DLL functions

Tags: c++, dll, shared-libraries

Is there a way to load all functions from runtime loaded DLL? Current code:

```
hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibrary(dll);

typedef int(*f_connection_a)(args);
typedef int(*f_connection_b)(args);
typedef int(*f_connection_c)(args);

f_connection_a connection_a = (f_connection_a)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "connection_a");
f_connection_b connection_b = (f_connection_b)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "connection_b");
f_connection_c connection_c = (f_connection_c)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "connection_c");
```

As you can see, this gets cumbersome quickly as you have to define every DLL function like this. Is there a way to load all DLL functions instead of having to list them?

Comment: And, how do you plan to call those functions, without having called `GetProcAddress`, to get the entry point address for some function? In addition, here you aren't _loading_ functions. Whole .dll gets loaded with `LoadLibrary` call, so by the time it returns - all functions are already loaded.

Comment: I was inquiring whether there was a way to automate this process.

Comment: You can export a single function that returns array of pointers to all the other functions in this library.

Comment: @VTT but that would still mean that I'd have to list them manually in my library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since here the "connection_*" are only a variables, there is no way to initialize them other than to run a code such as calling a function to get an address of a function. WinAPI doesn't have bulk method for binding functions at run time. This is limitation of WinAPI. The intention of this method was to check the presence of a functions individually and to delay loading library up to the point when it will actually be needed (or to avoid loading at all if it is not used).

But you can avoid such messy code by binding DLL at program loading stage using Import Table feature. In this case Windows loads executable image into memory, then loads all dependent DLLs and automatically binds the imported functions *before* launching executable code. For this you need:

1. Prepare *.def file for the library you need to load. The simplest method is to launch "**impdef.exe my.dll**" command on dll file. You may find tiny *impdef.exe* that doesn't need installation in TinyC package (see https://bellard.org/tcc/).
2. Then prepare corresponding *.lib file by launching "**lib /def:my.def /out:my.lib**"
3. After that link produced library with your project as regular library.

The drawback of this method is that if DLL is absent or corrupted, your executable file won't start at all. But this is a small payment for the convenience of importing functions.